# The command tempmute is already an existing command or alias

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, categories

```
class My_Cog(commands.Cog, name='Moderation'):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @client.command()#tempmute command
    async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, d, *, reason=None):
        guild = ctx.guild

        for role in guild.roles:
            if role.name == "Muted":
                await member.add_roles(role)

                embed = discord.Embed(title="muted!", description=f"{member.mention} has been tempmuted ", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
                embed.add_field(name="reason:", value=reason, inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="time left for the mute:", value=f"{time}{d}", inline=False)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)

                if d == "s":
                    await asyncio.sleep(time)

                if d == "m":
                    await asyncio.sleep(time*60)

                if d == "h":
                    await asyncio.sleep(time*60*60)

                if d == "d":
                    await asyncio.sleep(time*60*60*24)

                await member.remove_roles(role)

                embed = discord.Embed(title="unmute (temp) ", description=f"unmuted -{member.mention} ", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)

                return
```

Hi everyone! What is the command tempmute is already an existing command or alias. in Python? What does it do?  I cant understand why cant i create a cog, when this command is in the class? It gives me an error. I dont know what to do

Comment: Well, do you have 2 commands named `tempmute`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class My_Cog(commands.Cog, name='Moderation'):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(aliases=['tempmute'])#tempmute command
    async def temp_mute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, d, *, reason=None):
        guild = ctx.guild

        for role in guild.roles:
            if role.name == "Muted":
                await member.add_roles(role)

                embed = discord.Embed(title="muted!", description=f"{member.mention} has been tempmuted ", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
                embed.add_field(name="reason:", value=reason, inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="time left for the mute:", value=f"{time}{d}", inline=False)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)

                if d == "s":
                    await asyncio.sleep(time)

                if d == "m":
                    await asyncio.sleep(time*60)

                if d == "h":
                    await asyncio.sleep(time*60*60)

                if d == "d":
                    await asyncio.sleep(time*60*60*24)

                await member.remove_roles(role)

                embed = discord.Embed(title="unmute (temp) ", description=f"unmuted -{member.mention} ", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)

                return
```

You can try this to get rid of the error, but check around and see if you have another command named tempmute. Also, while in a cog, use "@commands.command".

Comment: Now i can create categories, but commands does not working